# Change NginX default page to blank using Ansible

Tags: nginx, ansible

How to change NginX default page to blank using Ansible?

I need to change the default `Welcome to nginx!` page to blank.

Comment: Create a task to edit the `/var/www/html/index.html`. This can either be done using your own custom template (`.j2`) with the `template` module, or you can use a custom static file and just copy it (`copy` module), replacing the old index.html

Comment: It can be woth taking a look at the modules: `blockinfile`, `lineinfile` and `replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example below the module `file` is being used to simply delete existing index.html and creates an empty one.

```
- hosts: webserver
  tasks:
    - name: Delete file
      file:
        path: /var/www/html/index.html
        state: absent

    - name: Create empty index.html file
      file:
        path: /var/www/html/index.html
        state: touch
```